# Appending Div after AJAX post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, vb.net

I'm struggling to understand why the following is occurring. I am calling a very simple webservice as shown below. For some reason, my jquery appends the div, but it vanishes immediately? Apologies for the poorly formatted thread...

Also, using jquery 1.7.1 as provided by VS2013

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Function GetTime() As String
    Dim time As String = ""
    time = Now().TimeOfDay.ToString

    Return time
End Function
```

My AJAX below

```
 function CallWebServiceFromJquery() {

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "WebService.asmx/GetTime",
             data: "{}",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: setTime,
             error: OnError

         });

     }
```

Success function

```
function setTime(data, status) {
         //alert(data.d);
         $("#time").css("visibility", "visible")
         $("#time").append("<h1>" + data.d + "</h1>")
     }
```

Lastly, the onclick

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCallWebService" runat="server" OnClientClick="CallWebServiceFromJquery()" Text="Call Webservice" />
```

Comment: I should add, when used, the alert returns the current time!

Comment: you are trying to concatenate an object and a string. Does `#time` exist when this code is run?

Comment: Amended post - with correct object structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button click itself is causing a postback, hence why the appended `div` seems to disappear. You need to stop the default event behaviour using `preventDefault()`:

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="CallWebServiceFromJquery(event)" ...
```

```js
function CallWebServiceFromJquery(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        // ajax settings...
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `CallWebServiceFromJquery` returns `false`. Based on your description of the div appearing and disappearing, your page is doing a postback.

Comment: Use comments to ask for clarification. This is not an answer and should be deleted

Comment: Let me clarify, I added return false, it worked. Hence answer, not comment. Appearing and vanishing immediately suggests a postback.

Comment: It was originally a question and has been edited several times since. had it been a proper crafted answer in the first place there wouldn't have been an issue

Comment: A question, followed by steps on how to correct the situation. I edited it to address your criticism.